# When to use a cloud

Tags: web-applications, cloud

I am bit confused with the cloud concept and especially when to use it to benefit from it.

I am working on a Web Based Project and have the following questions:

1. just Setting up the Systems DB in the Internet makes the structure
   cloud?
2. What are the benefits of making my web application cloud?

The users accessing the the DB are limited (20-30) and the data transacted on daily basis are of medium amount (100-200MB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain cloud computing segments in details to understand Cloud Computing.

Cloud computing: Cloud computing is the practice of using a network of remote servers hosted on the Internet to **store**, **manage**, and **process data**, rather than a local server or a personal computer.

Cloud Computing Segment:

IaaS(Infrastructure as a Service) - Infrastructure as a Service is a provision model of cloud computing in which an organization **outsources the equipment** used to support operations, **including storage, hardware, servers and networking components**. The service provider owns the equipment and is responsible for housing, running and maintaining it. The client typically pays on a per-use basis. Ex- [Amazon Web Services](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CEUQFjAA&url=http://aws.amazon.com/&ei=1ebxUrXPHsTqrAed64HgAg&usg=AFQjCNF6l7Qvv42D4hQAm-XuRkoG8ZezHw&bvm=bv.60799247,d.bmk), [BlueLock](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://www.bluelock.com/&ei=xObxUoS9IIWVrAekgYGACg&usg=AFQjCNH42q51zAqBXL1Ch7r9TEnESKbuPA&bvm=bv.60799247,d.bmk), [Cloudscaling](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://www.cloudscaling.com/&ei=sebxUrreJMmBrQfT_YHQCg&usg=AFQjCNFqc5Vg8R7GiWpamsyJdq2--KPAHg&bvm=bv.60799247,d.bmk) and [Datapipe](http://www.datapipe.com/)

PaaS(Platform as a Service) - Platform as a Service is one of the GROWING sector of cloud computing. PaaS basically help developer to speed the development of app, saving money and most important innovating their applications and business instead of setting up configurations and managing things like servers and databases. In one line I can say **Platform as a service (PaaS) automates the configuration, deployment and ongoing management of applications in the cloud.** Ex: [Heroku](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/paas-heroku-dynos-cloud-computing-web-application,2-601.html), [EngineYard](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/paas-engine-yard-amazon-elastic-cloud-computing,2-578.html), [App42 PaaS](http://app42paas.shephertz.com/) and [OpenShift](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/red-hat-openshift-paas-open-source-cloud-computing,2-595.html)

SaaS(Software as a Service) - Software as a Service, SaaS is a **software delivery method** that provides access to software and its functions remotely as a Web-based service. Ex: [Abiquo's](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.abiquo.com/&ei=AunxUtm7LtCqrAeUyoGQAw&usg=AFQjCNHCqCjH9Rxmx9QhzGqYhkVrX7jFxg&sig2=gOtWoqZ4yLYu21KnbrrY_g&bvm=bv.60799247,d.bmk) and [Akamai](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.akamai.com/&ei=XenxUojXAo2GrQe2qIG4Aw&usg=AFQjCNFAg1-mUKzl8EA-qUeCeqivsNE1iA&sig2=cMF2q2n_b0Ddu0lhX6qOOA&bvm=bv.60799247,d.bmk)

BaaS(Backed as a Service) - Backend as a service (BaaS), also known as "mobile backend as a service" (MBaaS),is a model for providing web and mobile app developers with a way to link their applications to backend cloud storage while also providing features such as user management, push notifications, and integration with social networking services. Exp: [Kinvey](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.kinvey.com/&ei=KOrxUrGpGoiPrQf77YHYCA&usg=AFQjCNHW07RdY9uxaYXcpZ4MkPbj-T1izg&sig2=Zv2xNPKXy302lJVxMeoeIg&bvm=bv.60799247,d.bmk), [StackMob](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=https://www.stackmob.com/&ei=POrxUqCrDMH_rQe5r4DoAQ&usg=AFQjCNFhfc1zFrgdA13dK8803stcF5DbXw&sig2=uVcVAXA_PkIzcYKenzLF0w&bvm=bv.60799247,d.bmk), [App42 API](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://api.shephertz.com/&ei=UerxUr2GH4uYrAe6loGYAg&usg=AFQjCNHP957JYg-jxfrwjVQ64oyY50N0jQ&sig2=VQc_QvvL_OOGI2iS3t6ybw&bvm=bv.60799247,d.bmk) and [Parse](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http://parse.com/&ei=aurxUoODJpHQrQfWnID4DQ&usg=AFQjCNF7LyFPdX7EuARiDAYtfqiaAsajPA&sig2=voX4_zXnIYdE3im7H4GGTw&bvm=bv.60799247,d.bmk)

I think you are looking Backed Service provides for you application. You can go with BaaS providers.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the benefits are:

- You don't need to have any infrastructure on your end
- You can enable the services you need and just pay for them (On a PaaS)
- Easily scale up/down (horizontally or vertically) your application (On a PaaS)
- Pay for the usage you do.

However, you will need to choose between an IaaS and a PaaS.

- IaaS: You get the Infrastructure as a Service where you have to take care of the installation/configuration/updating process of the services you want to use. Benefit: Very customizable.
- PaaS: You will get a MySQL database, a Tomcat webserver, ... as a Service. So with one click of your mouse you can start using a MySQL database, or deploy your Tomcat application.

For example, [this](http://www.comtechies.com/2013/03/how-to-create-and-connect-cloudbees.html#.UbBACECpqvs) is way you can use a MySQL on a PaaS.